# Aggregating Virtual Fields in the QGIS Layout

Tags: print-composer, aggregate, virtual-field

I have an atlas creating maps of parks. These parks contain different areas with different types of surfaces, which need to be managed differently.

In my map-layout I'd like to summarise the area of all different kinds of surfaces per park and I'm using the following function to display that (example for all Lawns in a certain Park):

`[%aggregate(layer:='surfaces',aggregate:='sum',expression:="area",  filter:="parknumber"=attribute( @atlas_feature, 'parknumber' ) AND "Type"='Law')%]`

Needless to say, that the surface layer and the park layer are linked in a 1:n relation via the `parknumber`.

What seems not to work, is making the `"Area"` field a virtual field, so when geometries change, the area calculation changes automatically and the information in my map-layout changes automatically, too.

Or phrased differently, the aggregate function does not find/accept the virtual fields in the table.

Is there anything I could do, to get this solved?

Comment: Sure :) Sorry for the typo!